# Long URL in php using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I have a very long URL: `//domain/administration/registrar/term_detail.php?a_id=47`
And I want to make it looks like: `//domain/administration/registrar/detail/47`

I have created an htaccess file in `//domain/administration/registrar/`. Below is my code in htaccess and it is not working. Any suggestion of what I did wrong is appreciated.

Both of my `htaccess` and `term_detail.php` files are inside of `registrar` folder.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /administration/registrar/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+registrar/detail\.php\?a_id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ administration/registrar/%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^administration/registrar/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ detail?a_id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try these rules inside your `/administration/registrar/.htaccess`:

```bash
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /administration/registrar/

## External redirect to /administration/registrar/term_detail/47
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^./]+)(?:\.php)?\?a_id=([^&\s]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2? [R=301,L,NE]

## Internal rewrite to term_detail.php?a_id=47
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ $1.php?a_id=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: I tested it. It is working. I am also wondering if I am hiding my php extension in URL. So my long URL is looks like this: //domain/administration/registrar/term_detail?a_id=47 Would that work with your code above?

Comment: Check my updates. It should work with `//domain/administration/registrar/term_detail?a_id=47` now

Comment: Thank you Sir. Can you also post your first code? I want to compare both codes.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I have accepted your answer. Could you also post your first code? When the url is (I forgot to save it before you edited your answer): //domain/administration/registrar/term_detail.php?a_id=47

Comment: @QQ10: This answer will redirect both `/administration/registrar/term_detail?a_id=47` and `/administration/registrar/term_detail.php?a_id=47` URLs

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples and attempts please try following .htaccess rules file. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

Keep your htaccess file inside registrar folder.

```
RewriteEngine ON
##External redirect to //domain/administration/registrar/detail/47 URL.
RewriteBase /administration/registrar/
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/(?:[^_]*)_([^.]*)\.php\?a_id=(\S+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2/%3/%4? [R=301,L]

##Internal rewrite to term_detail.php file.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ $1/$2/term_$3.php?a_id=$4 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: I copied this code and entered URL: //domain/administration/registrar/term_detail.php?a_id=47. This url goes to: //domain/administration//detail/45. There is a extra "/" before detail. It showed me page not found - 404 error.

Comment: @QQ10, oh sorry there was a typo, I have fixed it now. Please do place new edited rules and let me know how it goes, cheers.

Comment: It is going correct url now. /administration/registrar/detail/52 that is what I am expecting. But for some reason, my content is not displaying. I got page can not found with new url.

Comment: @QQ10, ok so my code assumes that your `htaccess` file resides along with administrator folder(not inside it but along side it), please make sure it is the case and let me know how it goes. Code is Good only we need to fix this one.

Comment: This is our root directory: /export/vol2/httpd/htdocs/administration/registrar. Every of my files are in registrar folder. I don't have permission to edit anything above it. term_detail.php and .htaccess are both in registrar folder. so, /export/vol2/httpd/htdocs/administration/registrar/term_detail.php and /export/vol2/httpd/htdocs/administration/registrar/htaccess

Comment: @QQ10, ok sure, I have edited my answer you can take a look and try it out and let me know how it goes, cheers.